# Using single cursor for many instances

Tags: android, sqlite

I came across this info that not closing the cursor or database gobbles up memory. So as i use the cursor across a hundred test cases I might forget to close it somewhere. Can I declare a single cursor and reuse it again and again making different references and finally closing it in the OnDestroy() method.

```
Eg. Cursor a;

//Another function
a = as.rawQuery("select * from verse"+k, null);

//Another  function
a = bs.rawQuery("select * from hello", null); //Another database

//Another function
a =  cs.rawQuery("select * from chapter", null); //Another database

//OnDestroy()
a.close();
```

Is it a feasible solution??

Comment: I smells like incorrect design.

Comment: I came across singleton instance design. Are they both different?

Comment: Singleton should be sqlitedatabase instance. cursor should be unique for each method that provides some action for example inserting.

Comment: When I researched this once the best practice was to create a new Cursor object every time. So I guess you will have to try and remember to close the cursor after you have used it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a single cursor; each `rawQuery` call creates a new cursor object.
When you assign a reference to the new cursor object to `a`, the old object is not closed (and you cannot anymore reach it).

To ensure that `close` is always called, use try/finally:

```java
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(...);
try {
    ... read data ...
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

If you have a helper function that returns a cursor, do this in the calling function.